# How to reuse rgb value variable opacity color in React CSS Styled components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

i know that there are many answers that would perhaps resolve the issue i am having, however, i would love second opinion and possible a clean workaround.

I have simple css color variable in hex/rgba.

```
--complementary-contrast-alt-1: #4d4d51; (prefered format) or 
--complementary-contrast-alt-1: rgb(78, 78, 81) (alternative format);
```

So this variable should always be in the same format as it can be replaced from the backend:
However, i need to add opacity to it.
In a new variable i am implementing:

```
 --complementary-contrast-1-translucent:  rgba(var(--complementary-contrast-alt-1), 0.9);
```

The thing is that sadly this wont work unless the main variable is numbers:

```
 --complementary-contrast-alt-1: 78, 78, 78;
```

This of coarse raises more issues as the main variable works for my new variable but it does not work for everything else that is also using it.

I am looking for a solution which would not include JS functions. Some sort of work around that would simplify the outcome. Or if there is no way to make it without function, how could that look alike?.

Comment: What do  you want exactly?

Comment: I need to add opacity to a color in second variable that uses the main variable as reference.

Comment: Whether the 1st variable is in hex format or rgb, right?

Comment: So a general way to do it

Comment: hex or rgb yes.

Comment: We can also use RGB values like `rgb(255, 255, 255, .5)` where the last one is for alpha value. Can you get the variable name like this from the backend? @Siouxx

Comment: I guess that is a valid option. I was focusing on solving in on the frontend purely.

Comment: Why not have two versions of each color? A hex version and a version that's just the numbers. Then you can use the rgb version when you need transparency.

Comment: It is because, the main variable is dynamic.
User should be able, at any point, to change the color. And that is achieved by variable changing value from the backend CMS.

Comment: Then you will need to convert it to rgb in the frontend in order to add transparency.